# Setting a condition on MATLAB ode45 output (while running)

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm solving a system of ODEs with ode45 for many different parameters(these parameters are coefficients of differential equations) , and I want to find parameters for which the solution is smaller (not larger) than a given value.

How can I set a condition on ode45 , to "detect" automatically if the solution (for some of those parameters) gets larger than that (given) value **while solving** the system and **stop solving for further steps**?

Jan suggested to put the following condition in the definition of the input function so the int. I tried this, but it doesn't work: after a few steps (and although the condition is not correct yet) iteration ends soon with the output kept constant at some number. (an incorrect output)

(qm , U , V , etc are constants and X has 4 columns )

```
[T,X]=ode45(@acceleration,tspan,x0);


function xprime=acceleration(T,X)
   size_X=length(X);
    xprime=zeros (4,1);
        if X(size_X,1)>threshold

  xprime(1)=0;
  xprime(2)=0;
  xprime(3)=0;
  xprime(4)=0;

        else

  xprime(1)=X(3);
  xprime(2)=X(4);
  xprime(3)=X(1)*X(4)^2 - 2*qm*(U+V*(cos(w*T)))*F1(num,X(1),X(2));
  xprime(4)= -2*X(3)*X(4)/X(1) - qm*((U+V*(cos(w*T)))/(X(1)))*F2(num,X(1),X(2));

        end
  end
```

- What is the problem with the above code?
- Somebody suggested to attach a monitoring function to ode45 . ([here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5383/setting-a-condition-on-matlab-ode45-output?noredirect=1#comment10331_5383)) . Does anyone know how to do this?
  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't see built in options in the Matlab ODE solvers that may be (mis)used for your purposes.

But you can modify your right hand side in `y' = f(t,y)` accordingly. I may think of

- `IF y > threshold THEN f(t,y) = 0` -- this should lead to a fast end of the iteration because of the step size control in ODE45
- Or raising an exception, that only cancels current the iteration (Not sure how to do this ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I asked this question before at  scicomp.stackexchange , and there somebody suggested to attach a monitoring function to ode45. here: [link](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5383/setting-a-condition-on-matlab-ode45-output?noredirect=1#comment10331_5383). Do you now how to do this?

Comment: I tried your suggestion (as I wrote it in the question) . but it doesn't work.(as stated above) what is the problem with that?

Comment: The behavior is as expected. Maybe your switching condition is not right. Do you want to check the 4th component? Try to check whether size_X does what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Are you solving a set of equations or trying to integrate over time? Without more info it sounds like you should be using fsolve or fmincon?

If you really are integrating, I think you can use the Events functionality to indicate to ode45 that you want to stop. The ballode example might be helpful.